# Detect gamepad input with Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a counter app for a laboratory I have this 5 button "wand" plugged into my computer via USB the computer recognises it as a UHID Gamepad Device. I have no problem detecting normal keyboard but can't seem to detect GamePad button events.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have this plugged into your computer as you wrote, or into your Android device?   Does the android device have both software and hardware USB host support?  If the gamepad is not being recognized (and you don't feel like customizing the android install), you may need to talk to it the hard way using the USB host APIs.  If you do have rudimentary USB support on the android, you might find it easier to modify a numeric keypad which would probably be recognized as a keyboard (though you'll then need one of the invisible on-screen keyboard IMEs, or else tolerate it constantly popping up).

Comment: I have plugged in this Gamepad in both the PC and in the android tablet both do not detect it? How would I ensure both software and hardware support on android? @ChrisStratton

Comment: You will probably have to do extensive research on it and write a fair amount of code - that's why I'm suggesting you might want to switch to something with a more standard interface such as a numeric keypad.

Comment: I would use a numeric keypad but the problem is with a keypad you need the app in focus on windows but the same pad should be used on windows as on android so it need to be a Gamepad for both systems. The windows app is written in Delphi and access windows dll via wrappers. Has no one else interface generic gamepad device?

Comment: try another gamepad, because mostly gamepads are automatically detected in Windows and Android (linux). For Android u might need to try a few gamepads though. I use logitech's joystick and it is automatically detected in Android. You can use ApiDemos to check if ur gamepad is working or not.